# The bootstrap modal dialog box wont show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-cookie

Hello everyone after putting a javascript to my code that make the selected form stays even a user refreshed the page my modal dialog box wont shows up anymore.

My code do is switching form using single page (show/hide using javascript) but everytime i refreshed the page it goes to the default form and now i put a "jquery cookie plugin" code that makes the selected form stays even a user refresh the page.

My problem now is my modal dialog box wont show if i click the link to modal dialog.

script:

```
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(function(){

    var page = $.cookie( 'page' ),
        pages = $( '.container' ).children( 'div' );
        $('.myFirst').show();
    pages.hide();
    ( page === undefined ) || $( page ).show();
    $('#show_first,#show_second,#show_third').click(function(){
        var index = $(this).index( 'a[id^=show_]' ),
            curPage;
        curPage = '.' + pages.eq( index ).attr( 'class' );
        pages.hide().eq( index ).show();
        $.cookie( 'page', curPage );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

modal diualog link:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"> Modal Dialog</a>
```

modal dialog box code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form class="form-horizontal">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                                <button type="button" id="show_first" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">First</button>
                                                <button type="button" id="show_second" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Second</button>
                                                <button type="button" id="show_third" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Third</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />

    <div class="container">
            <div class="myFirst">
                <div class="row">
                    <center>
                        First Page
                    </center>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mySecond">
                <div class="row">
                    <center>
                        Second Page
                    </center>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="myThird">
                <div class="row">
                    <center>
                        Third Page
                    </center>
                 </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you have a modal with the id of `#myModal`, so you need to change the line:
`$('.myFirst').show();` to:
`$('#myModal').show();`

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by revising the code. According to bootstrap documentation container divs can't be nested so when I removed that it works.

```
           <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Modal Dialog</a>


                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
           hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form class="form-horizontal">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                            <button type="button" id="show_first" 
 class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">First</button>
                                            <button type="button" id="show_second" 
  class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Second</button>
                                            <button type="button" id="show_third" 
   class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Third</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```